# C# - Compiler Error: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, app-config, application-settings, settings.settings

Hey Everyone, 
How do I fix the Compiler Error upon compiling on "**return ((string)(this["TargetDir"]));**":

```
  System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled
  Configuration system failed to initialize
  {"Unrecognized configuration section userSettings/CCP.Settings1. (C:\\Users\\bmccarthy\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\CCP Utility\\CCP Utility\\bin\\Debug\\CCP_Utility.exe.config line 21)"}

  A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll
```

Here's the code in my Settings.Designer.cs file under the Properties directory:

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
    public string TargetDir {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["TargetDir"]));
        }
        set {
            this["TargetDir"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Here's the code for CCP_Utility.exe.config from the bin folder:

```
  <CCP_Utility.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="SourceDir" serializeAs="String">
      <value />
    </setting>
    <setting name="TargetDir" serializeAs="String">
      <value />
    </setting>
    <setting name="CorpID" serializeAs="String">
      <value />
    </setting>
  </CCP_Utility.Properties.Settings>

    <CCP_Utility.Settings1>
        <setting name="sourceDir" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="targetDir" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
    </CCP_Utility.Settings1>
```

What does the < CCP_Utility.Settings1 > tag have to match up to?? App.config and what else?

Does capitalization matter? I have the variable declared as TargetDir Settings.Settings....

Where is the System.Configuration.dll file located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify UserScopedSettingAttribute matches up with the correct settings section.

If I remember correct, yes, case-sensitive.

Usually, I will add a setting, save and close, then open the settings designer again, and delete the setting, save and close. This will get the designer in-sync. I have seen them get out-of-sync the first time the designer is opened on a computer. (For example, when you get from source control.)

Comment: thanks for the response! How do I do that? Going to the definition of UserScopedSettingAttribute under config gives me -  public sealed class UserScopedSettingAttribute : SettingAttribute { //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute  
public UserScopedSettingAttribute(); }

Comment: @Brian McCarthy: In your app.config there is a user section and an application section. I cannot tell from your posted section. Since you specified UserScopedSettingAttribute then you must have the full section in the config file. Make sure your sections are complete. (valid XML)

Answer (score 1):

I got the application to compile without compiler errors by changing the capitilzation of sourceDir and targetDir under CCP_Utility.Settings1 in the Settings1.Designer.cs file as follows:

```
<CCP_Utility.Settings1>
    <setting name="SourceDir" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
    </setting>
    <setting name="TargetDir" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
    </setting>
</CCP_Utility.Settings1>
```