# An exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an ASP.NEt MVC application with MySQL. Everything was running smoothly until I suddenly got this error after building the web project: 
**An exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code**

Here are the exception details:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232062
  Message=Échec de la recherche ou du chargement du fournisseur de données .Net Framework inscrit.
  Source=System.Data
  BareMessage=Échec de la recherche ou du chargement du fournisseur de données .Net Framework inscrit.
  Line=0
  StackTrace:
       à System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
       à System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
       à System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)
       à System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
       à System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
       à System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
       à System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
       à System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
       à System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
       à System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       à System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       à System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       à System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       à System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
       à System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
       à System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       à System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       à TheChef.Data.Infrastructure.RepositoryBase`1.GetAll() dans c:\Users\SEGOUR JUNIOR 1\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TheChef-RMS\TheChef.Data\Infrastructure\RepositoryBase.cs:ligne 72
       à TheChef.Service.EmployeService.RetrieveAll() dans c:\Users\SEGOUR JUNIOR 1\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TheChef-RMS\TheChef.Service\Personnel\EmployeService.cs:ligne 34
       à TheChef.Web.ControllerActionsHandlers.EmployeActionsHandler.List() dans C:\Users\SEGOUR JUNIOR 1\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TheChef-RMS\TheChef.Web\ControllerActionsHandlers\Personnel\EmployeActionsHandler.cs:ligne 57
       à TheChef.Web.Controllers.EmployeController.Index() dans C:\Users\SEGOUR JUNIOR 1\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TheChef-RMS\TheChef.Web\Controllers\Personnel\EmployeController.cs:ligne 50
       à lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       à System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       à System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       à System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       à System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
       à System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       à System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       à System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       à System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
       à System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       à System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       à System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException:
```

My application architecture follows that of  ASP.NET MVC Solution Architecture – Best Practices By Christos S. on February 15, 2015 just to give you an idea of how my solution is structured. 
When I launch debugging, execution stops at this line in the RepositoryBase.cs file:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    return dbSet.ToList();
}
```

What I have done so far to solve the issue:

1. Check configuration files, app.config in the Model project where I have an ADO Entity Data Model file and web.config in the Web project to see if something has changed.
2. Uninstall Visual Studio and all related .Net Framework installations and reinstall Visual Studio.
3. Google the error and/or its additional information provided on the yellow page. I found mainly StackOverflow.com related questions such as [ConfigurationErrorException in trying to run console app with MySQL Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597652/configurationerrorexception-in-trying-to-run-console-app-with-mysql-entity-frame) and [C# - Compiler Error: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316999/c-sharp-compiler-error-system-configuration-configurationerrorsexception-was) which didn't help much.

One more point: The error occurs only when I open a view that retrieves data from the database.

Please Help !

Comment: Have you debugged step by step to identify where error occurs?

Comment: @Blade: Yes, the error occurs at the line in the RepositoryBase.cs file. I pasted the exact code above. Whenever I hit the database to retrieve data, I run through this error or a similar one.

Comment: What is dbSet type? Can you show the entire repository class?